# OnCollisionEnter2D is being called with platform effector even though I haven't collided with it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I have a moving platform script. My platform is frozen unless I collide with it, then it starts moving. I have a platform effector so I can be able to jump on it from under it and not hit my head on it.
However `OnCollisionEnter2D` is getting called even though I'm under it and haven't physically collided with the one way collision. It's as if it's a trigger.

```
   private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        
        if (collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Player>())
        {
            Debug.Log("On Collision Enter");
            //CameraFollow.instance.useFixedDeltaTime = false;
            Player = collision.gameObject;
            PlayerScript = Player.GetComponent<Player>();
            amountOfTimesPlayerCollided++;
        }
```

Even if my head just touches the collider area (without hopping on the platform) the method gets called and "On Collision Enter" is logged into the console.
How do I make it so that OnCollisionEnter2D only gets called when I physically collide with the platform?

Thanks!
I'm using the latest version of Unity 2021 but this has happened to me with other versions in the past I'm pretty sure.

Comment: According to [Colliders -> Collision Action Matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) `OnCollisionEnter2D` is never invoked for *Triggers* ... apparently there is some collider which is **not** a trigger colliding. Have you tried [Debugging your code](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) with breakpoints and confirm which exact objects and colliders are involved in the collision?

Comment: A touch is a collision. It's unclear what you want exactly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This callback is [sent when an incoming collider makes contact with this object's collider](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html).

I think "contact" and "touch" have the same meaning, so this is an expected behavior.

> only gets called when I physically collide with the platform?

I guess you want to detect an impact, so you may also pay attention to the [velocity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision2D-relativeVelocity.html) between two objects when the collision occurs.

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Player>()
        && collision.relativeVelocity.magnitude > THRESHOLD)
    {
        ......
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I ended up doing that, sorry for not specifying what I needed. By touch I meant I didn't hit it but my collider was touching the area of the box collider. However I didn't expect it to call the method since I didn't physically hit it since it's a one way collision and I was under the platform. I ended up doing ```if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player") && PlayerScript.rb.velocity.y==0)```
Thanks and God bless

Comment: It was being a bit annoying still so I also added a trigger under the platform and I have a bool called ```playerIsUnder``` and I only do ```OnCollisionEnter2D``` stuff if the player isn't under.